Question about overriding cascade layers from a package
I have an input box which i had previously styled, I decided that I wanted an autocomplete feature and chose to use the autocomplete component provided in this package.
the documentation for this package states that it uses @layer to provide over-writable CSS. I thought that i would be able to add "className" followed by the name of the class i made to style my original text box but this seems to only be styling a wrapper that the component has.
what is the best way for me to apply these styles to the autocomplete component itself and not the wrapper surrounding it?
CSS for original button
.answer-input {
  width: 95%;
  height: 5vh;
  border-radius: 1vh;
  background-color: #242424;
  border: none;
  margin: 2.5%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Inter, system-ui, Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 200%;
  outline: none;
}



You can inspect that element from chrome element and then apply your desired css to the class mentioned there. Check what class is the child of the wrapper class that is directly attached to the input field
